# Render TableField

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I am using the [`TableField`](https://www.drupal.org/project/tablefield) module and trying to render a field of this type in a custom block. I have tried many different approaches but I am not able to get any output. For instance:

```
{{ product.entity.field_table.value }}
{{ product.entity.field_table.0.value }}
{{ product.entity.field_table.entity.field_table }}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I manage to output the table using the following code, but it does not seem to be the best solution:

```
{% for row in product.entity.field_table.entity.field_table.getValue().0.value %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ row.0 }}</td>
  <td>{{ row.1 }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: What is the proper structure? Have you debugged the code at all?

Comment: @Kevin - Yes I have tried to debug the code. I'm not sure how to show the entire structure. All other fields works fine, for instance I'm rendering a textarea named `field_ingrediens` like this: `{{ product.entity.field_ingredients.value }}`. The problem seems only to be with fields of type `TableField`.

Comment: I'm guessing the structure of the field is different.

Comment: @Kevin - Look at my update above.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but based upon your preliminary solution and using the output from `{{ dump(tableItem }}` (the dump is just commented out in the code below; also see code for meaning of `tableItem`), I was able to extend getting the necessary values in a generic way to output all the values of a given table. Also, after the table, the following code will output the caption of the tablefield widget. The `field_data_tables` is the machine name of the tablefield widget for this node. In reference to the original poster, the `node` in this code would correspond to the `product` in the OP.

Note that the code  also uses row and col counters because the last col and last row contain non-table values, so we have to exclude those in the `{% for ... %}` loops.

```
{# The tableItem is the array of table values in the tablefield widget #}
{# Last row & col contain non-table values so use counters to exclude last row & col #}

{% for tableItem in node.field_data_tables.getValue() %}

        {# dump(tableItem) #}

        {% set rowCount = tableItem['value'] | length %}

        <table border="1">
          {% set rowCounter = 1 %}

          {% for rows in tableItem['value'] if rowCounter < rowCount %}

            {%  set colCount = rows | length %}

            <tr>
              {% for i in 0..colCount-1 %}
                <td> {{ rows[i] }} </td>
              {% endfor %}
            </tr>

            {% set rowCounter = rowCounter + 1 %}
          {% endfor %}

        </table>

        {{ tableItem.caption }} <br>

      {% endfor %}
```